# Ubuntu 14.10 Nvidia 540m Optimus latest graphic driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I am using ubuntu 14.10 and 331.113 NVidia driver without an issue. However I would like to install the latest possible NVidia driver that would work with my GPU. The problem is that if I download and install driver from NVidia page, it installs but I'm unable to login to the system, having information in /var/log/syslog that gnome-session crashed. If I try to install package using terminal and xorg-edgers ppa, I do not see anything newer than nvidia-331 even after sudo apt-get update.

Could someone provide me some manual how to install latest NVidia driver in this case?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is not supported any more.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 14.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest drivers by adding the brand-new NVIDIA PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

And installing or upgrading the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```